# Python list, file sort

Tags: file, list, sorting, python-2.7, alphabetical

```
grades_list=open('student_grades.txt','r')
for x in grades_list.readlines():
ft=1
hf=0
hm1=0
hm2=0
hm3=0
hm4=0
z=x.split()

for w in z:

    if ft==1:
        ft=0
        hm=0
        name=w
    else:
        if hf==1:
            hf=0
            if hm==1:
               hm1=int(w)
            else:
                if hm==2:
                   hm2=int(w)
                else:
                    if hm==3:
                        hm3=int(w)
                    else:
                        if hm==4:
                            hm4=int(w)
        else:
            if w=='HM1':
                hm=1
                hf=1
            else:
                if w=='HM2':
                    hm=2
                    hf=1
                else:
                    if w=='HM3':
                        hm=3
                        hf=1
                    else:
                        if w=='HM4':
                            hm=4
                            hf=1

        list_values = [hm1, hm2, hm3, hm4]
        average = float(sum(list_values)) / len(list_values)
        print hm1, hm2, hm3, hm4, average
```

When I run the program I receive:

Robert 0 90 80 92 65.5
Britany 98 92 0 0 47.5
Don 86 93 100 94 93.25
Charles 86 0 0 96 45.5
Sam 90 0 70 0 40.0

I am trying to get the data to appear in alphabetical order:

Britany 98 92 0 0 47.5
Charles 86 0 0 96 45.5
Don 86 93 100 94 93.25
Robert 0 90 80 92 65.5
Sam 90 0 70 0 40.0

I have tried sorting using .sort() or sorted(set(x)) but I keep getting errors.  I do NOT want to sort the file itself, but I need it to sort once it reads the file, before it prints the numbers and averages.  Thank you!  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use `elif`, instead of infinite nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following,

```
lines = grades_list.readlines()
lines.sort()
```

and then continue to `split` and process each line.

Comment: Or equivalently and more concisely: `lines = sorted(grades_list)` which both slurps the lines and sorts them at once.